# NFS share supported on Server 2012 dynamic disk?

Tags: nfs, windows-server-2012

Creating NFS shares on server 2008 R2 spanned volumes (with dynamic disks) works however when I tried on 2012 I received an error. The same PowerShell command works on the C drive basic volume on 2012.

[image]

```
New-NfsShare -Name nfsshare -Path E:\nfsshare -Authentication All `
    -EnableAnonymousAccess:$true -NetworkName $env:COMPUTERNAME `
    -Permission ReadWrite

New-NfsShare : Failed to perform the requested operation.
    At line:1 char:1
    + New-NfsShare -Name nfsshare -Path E:\nfsshare -Authentication All -EnableAnonymo ...
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_NfsServerTasks:root/Microsoft/..._NfsServerTasks) [New-NfsShare], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x80070001,New-NfsShare
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an email back from the MS storage team (nfsfeed@microsoft.com) and they confirmed this doesn't work in 2012.

There is a hotfix that is apparently available from special request to MS - 2777475.

They said it was fixed in 2012 R2.

Comment: Fix available: 
Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 update rollup: December 2012
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779768

Answer (score 1):

The fix is available in:

> Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012 update rollup: December 2012

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2779768